# Switch grid size on button click

Tags: android

I am using RecyclerView and I want to change grid size on button click.

Grid size 1 before click :

![first image show grid size 1 before button click..][1]

Grid size 3 after click :

![second image show grid size 3 after button click..][2]

Help me please?

Comment: Did you tried to use setLayoutManager in button click handler?

Comment: yes i tried it gives error when  using getgridSpancount

Comment: Do you mean GridLayoutManager.getSpanCount()? And what the error you got?

Comment: Also, please, fix the pictures in your answer

Answer (score 0):

Just set a new `GridLayoutManager` on the `RecyclerView`:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(v.getContext(), 3));
        }
    });
```